# Accessing an app by another app

Tags: applications

For example: There is a lot of apps about of theme switch in Play Store. If switch dark or light(any theme switcher app), the related app(whatsapp, instagram, etc.) theme switches dark or light. Actually, what i want ask is how another apps access to related apps. How is possible? I hope I had explain, sorry for bad english.

Comment: There are quite a few ways apps can access other apps. But in the example you quote, no interaction between apps occur. Theme is controlled by the Android OS. Theme switch apps change global theme settings. So all apps which support different themes (e.g. light and dark) are affected.

Comment: Okay, I get it. If I want to do get(to computer app from app) messages or comment(any info), should I use API of related app?